# How to sync Flutter TextField with Firestore field?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have `task` document in Firestore, which has `todo` field, and `TextField` in the Flutter UI.

Please advice how to make the `textfield` synced with the `todo` field, i.e.

1. Any time, text in the `textfield` is changed as user's typing, update the `todo` field with the just typed value.
2. Any time, the `todo` field is updated (manually in the Firestore console or by other user), update the `textfield` with the most recent value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, supply a `TextEditingController` to the `TextField` (take a look at [this](https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes/) for a complete example).

For the first part of the question, you will need to provide a `listener` to the `TextEditingController`. This `listener` should trigger a function like so :

```
  Future<void> _updateTaskValue(String text) {
    Firestore().runTransaction((Transaction transaction) {
      Firestore.instance.document([PATH OF YOUR DOCUMENT]).updateData({"todo": text});
    });
  }
```

Assuming that `text` is the controller's `text` value. Note that `runTransaction` is used to avoid data concurrency.

For the second part of the question, you will have to listen to the document. To do so, declare into `initState` a `StreamSubscription` :

```
subscription = Firestore.instance.document("").snapshots().listen(
    (DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => this._onDatabaseUpdate(snapshot));
```

This subscription will trigger a function each time the content is updated (whether the current user updates the `TextField`, another users updates it, or manually from the back office).

The function called below simply updates the controller's `text` attribute with the new content :

```
void _onDatabaseUpdate(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  setState(() {
    _controller.text = snapshot.data["todo"];
  });
}
```

For a complete example, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jon-mly/5042580533fb58927acca88f75213677).

Answer (score 1):

1. TextField onChanged updates the value in firebase.
2. Listen for value change in firebase and update the value for TextField with TextEditingController.

Here is the code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TODO Screen',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: TODOScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TODOScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TODOScreenState createState() => _TODOScreenState();
}

class _TODOScreenState extends State<TODOScreen> {
  final _ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('todo_id').child('value');
  TextEditingController _todoController = new TextEditingController();

  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subscription = _ref.onValue.listen((data) {
      String value = data.snapshot.value as String ?? "";
      updateOnChanged(value);
    });
  }

  saveOnChanged(String value) async {
    await _ref.set(value);
  }

  updateOnChanged(String value) async {
    setState(() {
      _todoController.value = _todoController.value.copyWith(
        text: value,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TODO Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "TODO"),
            maxLines: 5,
            onChanged: saveOnChanged,
            controller: _todoController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _todoController.dispose();

    if (_subscription != null) _subscription.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Hope it hepls!