# How do I make a search in Firestore feeds a pickerView in another ViewController?

Tags: search, google-cloud-firestore, label, textfield, uipickerview

I have a project in Xcode (storyboard) and I am trying to make a search in a database in my Firestore on my 1st ViewController with a search bar (it could be a textfield as well); no results should be displayed in a tableview, instead it should feed a picker view in my 2nd viewController; after that, right above my picker view I have a textfield that display the choice of the picker view; and below that I have a label that should display the same text as the above textfield.
Very simple. Any suggestion? highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to return the values from Firestore, getting a `DocumentSnapshot` and using this reference to the collection, to set the value on your textfield or other fields.

I would recommend you to take a look at the post from the Community [How to sync Flutter TextField with Firestore field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456308/how-to-sync-flutter-textfield-with-firestore-field)  that provides a full example of how to use Firestore and updating displaying fields. This example is in Flutter, which I believe should help you even in case you are not using Flutter.

Besides that, this other below question from Stack should provide you some more insights on how to achieve that.

- [How to fetch the data from cloud_firestore and display it in the TextField in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918010/how-to-fetch-the-data-from-cloud-firestore-and-display-it-in-the-textfield-in-fl)

Let me know if the information helped you!